# Get Largest Number from a list of numbers

Tags: java

```
    public void getJustRevisionsNumberData(String duaNum) {
    List<Number> dua = new ArrayList<Number>();
    dua = getRevisionsNum(duaNum); 

    // dua object -> 123, 843, 455, 565
    // I want 843

    for(Number number : dua) {

        System.out.println(number);

    }
}
```

**getRevisionsNum**

```
    public List<Number> getRevisionsNum(String duaNum) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();

    AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(session);
    return auditReader.getRevisions(DuaVO.class, duaNum);
```

I'm trying to get the largest number but unable to come up with a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you paste the "getRevisionNum()" method code?

Comment: Math.max() or override compareTo

Comment: sort the list and return the first one.

Comment: Numbers are not comparable by default - so you should either use a subtype (BigDecimal? Double? Integer?) or define a rule to compare them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the largest number you've come across so far in another variable like `largestNumber`, and then once you've iterated through the whole set, you can just print it out with a `System.out.println(largestNumber)` outside of the loop.

```
double largestNumber = Double.MIN_VALUE;
for(Number number: dua)
{
    if(number.doubleValue() > largestNumber)
        largestNumber = number;
}
System.out.println(largestNumber);
```

Setting `largestNumber` to `Double.MIN_VALUE` ensures that even if you're dealing with very large negative numbers, they should still satisfy `number.doubleValue() > largestNumber`. Calling `.doubleValue()` in the comparison is necessary so that you'll have two `double`s to compare.

Comment: The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Number, int

Comment: Oops, forgot we were using `Number` here. Try using `number.intValue()` instead of `number` in the comparison, as I've edited in.

Comment: That won't work if the numbers are 0.1, 0.3 and 0.2 as `intValue` will return 0 for all three...

Comment: @assylias I had assumed `int` values because of the examples given (123, 843, 455, 565). I've edited to work in a broader context.

Comment: If the Numbers are BigDecimals or BigIntegers or even Longs that may still not work in all cases... But the question is admittedly not very clear...

Comment: Its only gonna be an Integer

Answer (score 0):

That sounds simple!
Here is an example i made that works for a collection of Integers:

```
**  public int findMax(Collection<Integer> nums) {
    int temp = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // we want it to have the lowest value possible, else if we initialise it to 0 and the largest number is less than 0 it will not work.
    for (int i : nums) {// loop through the nums and we find the max number between temp and i and that is the new value of temp (So if i=10 and temp=1 then temp will be come 10)
        temp = Math.max(i, temp);
    }
    return temp;//we return the largest number found.
}

public int findMax(Collection<Integer> nums) {
    int temp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i : nums) {
        if(i > temp) temp = i;//similar with the code above, the only difference here is instead of calling a method over and over we perform a simple check and if it turns to be true (i is more than temp)  then temp gets the value of i.
    }
    return temp;
}**
```

Hope that helped you!

Answer (score -1):

One approach is you can sort the collection, and pick the first or last number (depending on how you sort). But sorting harms performance.

You could also loop through the list and if the new number is larger than the current stored number, it is replaced. As in:

```
public int getMax(ArrayList list){
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i) > max){
            max = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Which is basically what Collections.max(yourcollection) does, I believe.

Comment: Convert it to something that does work with >, number.doubleValue().. Not compile..?